# Use zend-servicemanager version 3 in Zend Framework 2 app

Tags: php, zend-framework2, migration, zend-framework3

The Zend Framework will be upgraded component by component to version 3. 
New version of the most essential components is stable: **[zend-servicemanager v3](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/releases/tag/release-3.0.0)**

The question is how  to use new **zend-servicemanager v3** in the "old" ZF application version 2 ?

There is a [migration guide](http://zend-servicemanager.readthedocs.org/en/latest/book/migration/) which explains how to use and what is new  in zend-servicemanager v3, but there isn't some kind of install guide for the new component.

Comment: Right now, zend MVC component still uses SM v 2.* so you won't be able to switch to higher version in apps that rely on MVC. Other components also can rely on SM v 2.*. When MVC will be released in version that supports service manager v3 you should be able to simply change dependency version constraint in composer config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZF3 is released so this shouldn't be a problem any more.

There is an up-to-date migration guide for the entire [application](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/migration/to-v3/application/) and for each [component](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/migration/to-v3/components/).